# QGIS georeferencing plugin workaround

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, georeferencing

I need to georeference an image. I had QGIS 3.2 installed. When I clicked on "Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins" QGIS froze. So, I tried installing 3.8 and the same things happened.  Tried 3.4, same result. Tried uninstalling old versions, restarted computer...same result.  There is an old bug report referencing this problem: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19526

Is there a known solution to this freezing, or alternatively, a workaround that will allow me to georeference in QGIS without needing to use "Manage and Install Plugins"?

For instance, could I manually install a georeferencing plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The georeferencer plugin is a core plugin, so you don't need to install it. You just need to enable it, which is much easier. If you need access to other (non-core) plugins, see this questions for instructions to install a plugin without using the Plugin Manager: [How to install a QGIS plugin when offline?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/26979/81764)

**How to *enable* an already installed plugin without opening the Plugin Manager:**

1. Find your QGIS user profile file. On Windows, it should be in this folder (substitute your username):

   > C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS

   See this question for more information if you have trouble finding your user profile: [Save and load user profiles in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188298/save-and-load-user-profiles-in-qgis)
2. Open the file called `QGIS3.ini`. It should open in a text editor, eg Notepad.
3. Search for "georefplugin". It should be in the `[plugins]` section, near the end of the file.

   [image]

**Make sure QGIS is closed before making any changes.** (I don't actually know what happens if QGIS is open when you make changes to the active user profile file. Maybe nothing, or maybe QGIS crashes, or maybe something worse. I chose to remain ignorant.)

4. Change `georefplugin=false` to `georefplugin=true`. Save and close the file.
5. Open QGIS. The georeferencer plugin should be enabled.

Note: I actually did this on my computer, and it worked as described. I don't have any trouble opening the plugin manager, so I can't promise that this will solve your issue. Please let me know whether it works for you.

Update:

This method also worked for Cody. Their experience differed slightly from mine:

1. Windows hid the directory "AppData..." when they tried to navigate to it from the file explorer. They accessed it by searching the C:\ drive.
2. The "georefplugin=..." line was not present in their .ini file. They added it to the file in the position I indicated. That worked to enable the georeferencer plugin.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. A couple of notes:
1) Windows hid the directory "AppData..." from me when I tried to navigate to it from the file explorer. I did a search on my C:\ drive in order to access it.
2) The "georefplugin=..." line was not present in my .ini file. So, I added it to the file in the position that you indicated.

Thank you!

Comment: Excellent notes. I added them into my answer. I wonder if the missing "georefplugin=..." line is a symptom of the same issue that causes QGIS to crash when you try to open the plugin manager.